# Win10 eliminating / reduce Post-Boot time for faster start into a program?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance-monitor

For a project I'm optimizing the time it takes for Windows 10 (Ent 64bit LTSB (1607)) to boot and start a specific program.
One of my main problems is what appears to be a longer post-boot pause, where Windows almost seems idle (looking at Windows Performance Recorder & Analyzer traces).

"Windows Init" is done, entering a 15-20s "Post Boot" Phase with no concerning HDD, CPU, Memory activity. I fail to see / understand what is going on here.
Ideally, the application in questions starts right away.

Another thought: Is there a way to prioritize the application to start-up earlier?
There is enough headroom to not cause any bottlenecks, starting it up earlier.

I have also tried to replace the Explorer.exe shell with the program in question. It makes no difference, the "Post-Boot" time is still present.

Many thanks.